# Converting Vignette Portlets to Liferay Portlets

Tags: liferay, portal

As the title states, i'm trying to convert these Vignette portlets into Liferay portlets.

Is there any documentation on this anywhere? I've searched the entire Internet

-When trying to deploy my WARs right off the bat, I'm getting a "missing liferay.plugin.packet.xml" which tells me the entire portlet must be reconfigured to work with Liferay.

-Running Liferay 6.1.1 ga2 on Web Logic 12c server

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You mean "liferay-plugin-package.xml", don't you?
You will find such a file in the source of Liferay at /portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.xml. For other examples just download sources from other Portlets (Github or Liferay-Marketplace).

Besides some other values, this file defines how Liferay should handle your war (layout-template, portlet, theme).

EDIT: As the marketplace does not allow (plz see the comment in: liferay-plugin-package_6_1_0.dtd) portlets having an liferay-plugin-package.xml, I would recommend to use the corresponding properties file.
Reference file (in the portal sources): /definitions/liferay-plugin-package_6_1_0.properties